# $f>0$ almost everywhere implies $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu >0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove this statement:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a measurable function. Show: $f>0$ almost every $\Rightarrow$ $\int_M f \, \mathrm{d}\mu >0$ for all $M\in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(M)>0$.

**Idea:**

Since $f>0$, we have $M=\bigcup \limits_{n\geq 1}E_n$ where $ E_n = \left\{x \in E: f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$ Since $\mu(M)>0$ for all $M\in \mathcal{M}$, there is some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(E_n)>0$. Otherwise $M$ could be expressed by a countable uinion of zero sets. Thus we have:$$\int_E f \, d\mu>\int_{E_n} f \, d\mu> \int_{E_n} \frac1n \, d\mu= \frac{\lambda(E_n)}{n} > 0$$

I realised that I dind't use the "almost everywhere", how can I deal with this?

Comment: The union of the $E_n$ might not be all of $M$. You also need the set of all $x$ where $f(x)\le0$.

Comment: You can redefine $f$ on a set of measure $0$ without changing the integrals.

Comment: Is that a zero set then? Could you please elaborate, I am really unfamiliar with this argumentation